# how to change z-index on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer. Okay, so- I made a popup kinda thing with an onclick event and it is on top of my posts wrapper - but because it's on top, I can't scroll down, which is why I changed the z-index. I could scroll again, but when I clicked on the link, the popup appeared behind my posts wrapper and no matter what I do and change the z-index to, it stays behind the wrapper or is on top and makes it unable to scroll. I want the popup to have a lower z-index than my wrapper when *not* clicked, and a higher z-index when clicked. How do I do this? I got the codes from my friend- so.. yeah, here ya go!

```
#wrapper{
   {block:IndexPage}
   width:270px;
   {/block:IndexPage}
   {block:PermalinkPage}
   width:270px;
   {/block:PermalinkPage}
   margin-top:100px;
   margin-right: 250px;
   margin-left: auto;
   height: 400px;
   overflow:scroll;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   background-color: transparent;
   background-repeat: repeat;
   margin-bottom:100px;
   padding:15px;
   border: 3px solid #f3f2f2;
   z-index: 300;

}
#gee {
  position: fixed;
  top:100px;
  width:297px;
  height:490px;
  right: 250px;
  font:10px;
  opacity: 0.0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color:  #f8f6f6;
  color: #cccbcb;
  z-index:400;
}
```

And the Javascript is this:

```
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a#clickbutton').click(function() {
      $('.t',this).toggle();
   });

   $("#gee").css({"opacity": "0.0", "z-index": "-10"});
   $("#clickbutton").toggle(
      function () {
         $("#gee").animate({"opacity": "1.0", "z-index": "400"}, "fast");
      },
      function () {
         $("#gee").animate({"opacity": "0.0", "z-index": "-30"}, "fast");
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't animate `z-index`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Actually, yes you can.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! I stand corrected! Good to know, although I would never and can't think of a use for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery animate doesn't work with `z-index`.

So, do it separately:

```
$("#gee").animate({"opacity": "1.0"}, "fast").css("z-index", "400");
```

and

```
$("#gee").animate({"opacity": "0.0"}, "fast").css("z-index", "-30");
```

That works because you can chain functions because everything returns the element(s) that was changed.